# Switch statement...expected pattern after case:

Tags: ios, swift3

After each case declaration in my switch statement, XCode is indicating there should be an expected pattern?

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)  {
    switch segue.identifier {
    case: "SegueToCommentRating"
            let commentRatingViewController = segue.destination as! CommentRatingViewController
            commentRatingViewController.post = self.post
            commentRatingViewController.delegate = self
    case: "SegueToLogin"
            let loginViewController = segue.destination as! LoginViewController
            loginViewController.managedObjectContext = managedObjectContext
    case: "SegueToEditCommentOrRating"
            let commentRatingViewController = segue.destination as! CommentRatingViewController
            commentRatingViewController.post = self.post
            commentRatingViewController.userWillEdit = true
            commentRatingViewController.delegate = self
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

An image of the errors:
[image]

EDIT:  I've tried what was suggested (moving :) I'm getting another odd error as seen in image below:
[image]

Comment: You need to put the `:` __after__ the pattern. `case "SegueToLogin":`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct code would be:

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let string = segue.identifier {
            switch string {
            case "SegueToCommentRating":
                let commentRatingViewController = segue.destination as! CommentRatingViewController
                commentRatingViewController.post = self.post
                commentRatingViewController.delegate = self
            case "SegueToLogin":
                let loginViewController = segue.destination as! LoginViewController
                loginViewController.managedObjectContext = managedObjectContext
            case "SegueToEditCommentOrRating":
                let commentRatingViewController = segue.destination as! CommentRatingViewController
                commentRatingViewController.post = self.post
                commentRatingViewController.userWillEdit = true
                commentRatingViewController.delegate = self
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }
```

Just move the ":" to after the value you compare for

Comment: Alex. Thanks for that.  Could you take a look at my edit.  I have added a second image, with errors that popped up when I implemented your suggestion.  Thanks!

Comment: I think if you do segue!.identifier, you won't need to use the "?". if not segue.identifier!. However, that unwraps the segue, which is fine as long as you know it can't possibly be null, otherwise it will cause a crash

Comment: I have edited my answer to unwrap segue.identifier safely.

Answer (score 2):

Change `case: "SegueToCommentRating"` to `case "SegueToCommentRating":`